# Binomial coefficient equal to $\binom nk + 3\binom{n}{k-1} + 3\binom{n}{k-2} + \binom{n}{k-3}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Find one binomial coefficient equal to the following expression:

$$\binom nk + 3\binom{n}{k-1} + 3\binom{n}{k-2} + \binom{n}{k-3}$$

I tried to expand using the definition of $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, but it was unwieldy. Which identities should I use?

Comment: I suppose 
$$
\binom{\binom nk + 3\binom{n}{k-1} + 3\binom{n}{k-2} + \binom{n}{k-3}}{1}
$$
does not count. =)

Comment: Expand the multiples and use [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) several times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking at:
$$\binom 30\binom nk + \binom31\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom32\binom{n}{k-2} + \binom33\binom{n}{k-3}$$
Apply [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2):

One could just repeatedly used [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule):

\begin{align*}
S&=\binom nk+3\binom n{k-1}+3\binom n{k-2}+\binom n{k-3}\\
&=\binom{n+1}k+2\binom{n+1}{k-1}+\binom{n+1}{k-2}\\
&=\binom{n+2}k+\binom{n+2}{k-1}\\
&=\binom{n+3}k
\end{align*}